# What is Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7); in OpenGL ES 20?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

How does the parameters work for it and exactly what is mProjMatrix getting from the method?

Also why is 'float mProjMatrix = new float[16];` declared with 16, could I have used another number instead?

```
    float mProjMatrix = new float[16];
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
```

Answer (score 9):

View frustum is just a visual representation of perspective projection that is used to convert  3D point in the world coordinate space to the 2D point on the screen.

There're multiple ways to define the projection matrix (at least that I used personally):

1. By specifying 6 clip planes
2. By specifying aspect ratio, far and near clipping planes, field of view angle

But in the end they all end up as a single 4x4 perspective transform matrix.

Here is a must read [article](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html).

Answer (score 0):

Near/far is clipping distance from viewpoint. 
Question is what the left/right and top/bottom values are, and as far as I understand [the OpenGL docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml) mean the values on the near plane. So you have to calculate these to be smaller if you want to define the width/height of your view at the point you look at (which is farer away than the near plane). Does it work like this on ES20, too?